# Can an Ether wallet address be traceable to a crypto exchange?

Tags: wallets, exchanges, identity

If an ETH wallet address was created upon the opening of a Binance or Coinbase account, is there anything in the address itself, or its activity, that can give clues as to whether it was in fact created on Binance or Coinbase (an exchange)? So that the tracer can approach that exchange and complain about that account's activity?

Comment: nothing in the address, these are completely random, otherwise they would be hackeable. Coinbase management accounts have been identified by Etherscan, so it is possible to know if an account has some relation to the exchange, but I don't think this info is public, most likely only experts who create databases know for sure if an account has transaction patters indicating its ownership to an exchange

Comment: how does Etherscan identify Coinbase addresses?

Comment: no, Etherscan doesn't identify accounts created at Coinbase, Etherscan labels Coinbase's management accounts, and by relation with the User you can deduce that he has (probably) an account there

Comment: what are coinbase management accounts

Comment: I don't know, but if you run a crawler on Etherscan it surely will pop up at some point. I have seen them there.

Comment: you call something by name but don't know what it is? could you link to or screenshot an example of a coinbase management account that popped out to you like you say

Comment: I have seen coinbase accounts when browinsg transactions, but I can't give you the addresses. I just don't store this info waiting for you to come and ask for it

Comment: you can implement a crawler and grep the downloaded pages for `coinbase` word

Comment: what does grep mean. whats a crawler

Comment: `grep` is a unix command used to search for regular expressions , and crawler is a robot that crawls web pages on a website